# Variable introduced to command in shell script does not work

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

This works exactly as expected:

```
echo -n 80 443 | xargs -d ' ' -I% bash -c 'socat TCP4-LISTEN:%,fork TCP4:123.123.123.123:% &'
```

But this version does not work. The $ip variable fails to pass, and results in IP being 0.0.0.0):

```
ip=$(cat ip.txt)
echo -n 80 443 | xargs -d ' ' -I% bash -c 'socat TCP4-LISTEN:%,fork TCP4:$ip:% &'
```

How do I make it work as intended?

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because the variable is in single quotes. The shell does not expand variables in single quotes, and I guess when socat sees an invalid IP it uses 0.0.0.0

Pass the port and ip as command line arguments to the bash body.

```bsh
ip=$(< ip.txt)    # this is a bash builtin equivalent to $(cat ip.txt)
printf '%s\n' 80 443 | xargs -I% bash -c 'socat "TCP4-LISTEN:$1,fork" "TCP4:$2:$1" &' bash % "$ip"
```

The 2nd "bash" gets assigned to $0.

Comment: Awesome, it works! I don't know why, but it works!

Comment: You may also pass `ip` as an environment variable with `ip=$ip bash -c ...`.